# Understanding Tagged Types and asInstanceOf

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I use tagged types from Miles Sabin gist:

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

trait MyTrait

def tag(s: String): String @@ MyTrait = s.asInstanceOf[String @@ MyTrait]
```

Which I can use like this (and it works):

```
scala> tag("lala")
res7: @@[String,MyTrait] = lala
```

My question is: how? How doesn't this throw `ClassCastexception`: `s.asInstanceOf[String @@ MyTrait]`. From my point of view, `"lala"` is of type String but not of type `String with { type Tag = MyTrait}` since it was instantiated like usual `String` object. What is the magic with `asInstanceOf` method?

Comment: `{ type Tag = MyTrait }` doesn't really exists at runtime, it's completely erase and only taken into account by the Scala compiler.

Comment: so what is happening in runtime when `s.asInstanceOf[String @@ MyTrait]` is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that the whole point of tagged types is to avoid runtime overhead, but this also means you can't expect runtime type checks to work for distinguishing them!

`asInstanceOf` is a runtime cast, and JVM doesn't know the Scala type system (or even Java's); it only has classes, interfaces, and primitives. So `asInstanceOf` can only cast to the *erased* type, i.e. the closest JVM equivalent of the Scala type. Erased type of `String with { type Tag = MyTrait}` is `String`, so it succeeds.

The relevant parts of the specification are:

1. [Standard Library](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html) defines `asInstanceOf` as follows:

   ```
   /** Type cast; needs to be inlined to work as given */
   def asInstanceOf[A]: A = this match {
     case x: A => x
     case _ => if (this eq null) this
               else throw new ClassCastException()
   }
   ```
2. [Type patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns) explains how `x: String with { type Tag = MyTrait }` is matched:

   > Types which are not of one of the forms described above are also accepted as type patterns. However, such type patterns will be translated to their erasure. The Scala compiler will issue an "unchecked" warning for these patterns to flag the possible loss of type-safety.
3. [Finally](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#type-erasure),

   > The erasure of a compound type `T1 with … with Tn {R}` is the erasure of the intersection dominator of `T1,…,Tn`.

   In this case `T1` is `String`, `T2` is `AnyRef { type Tag = MyTrait }`, so you get the intersection dominator of `String` and `AnyRef`, which is `String`.

Comment: so after type erasure `s.asInstanceOf[String @@ MyTrait]` becomes `s.asInstanceOf[String]` ?

Comment: @ka4eli Yes. Same for `isInstanceOf`, pattern matching, etc.

Comment: @ka4eli I've expanded the answer with some details.

Comment: is this a valid type notation: `AnyRef { type Tag = MyTrait }` ?